# How to show add new items page of list in a div

Tags: 2013, navigation, hide-elements

Is there any way I could only show `NewForm.aspx` in a div without showing Ribbon or Side Navigation at all ?

Its SharePoint 2013 but I also want to know if its possible with Office 365 too?

Comment: You can do this using CSS. Add the CSS on the page to hide the elements you want

Comment: the way I am adding div, i am having 2 navigations and 2 ribbons, one in div and one on the main page, i want to hide the div's one

Comment: Yes you can use Browser tools to find the element ID and then use it as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: both id's would be same, won't it ?

Comment: In that case you can target it like `#DivID #sideNavBox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the page in SharePoint Designer and then add CSS to hide the elements you want

For Example, in SharePoint Online you can use below CSS to hide the Quick Launch (Left Navigation)

```
#sideNavBox {
    display:none;
}
```

For targeting ID inside Div, you can use `#DivID #sideNavBox`